# How To Make A images/video Transition Animation Like in the kizoa App

Tags: ios, video, core-animation, calayer

I am working on an application using Swift.

I really worked hard to do this and I have done a major part of it. 
Actually the application takes some photos and a music file and then merges them into a video that can be played at a computer or web-like photo slideshow like this [Sample video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1knyOUIL6KcavK7wVtbNnboeqvHH15kSL/view?usp=sharing)

i am creating video from images using [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46560615/11316906).

Everything is working fine but i needed some special animation like Halo, Like app and also Kizoa App.

I need to use convert images into video with animation. and convert into mp4 file.

**P.S. : Let me know if any paid library of that**

Please help