# Swift | Creating video out of image array

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, xcode

I build a App, where user can make a Video of a few images. 
I took the code from this post: [Making video from UIImage array with different transition animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46315867/making-video-from-uiimage-array-with-different-transition-animations)

Everything is working fine, but I have one big problem and I don't know how to solve it.

When the video was created, the image is not filling the hole screen and sometimes it turns to another side or the image is cut in half.

First image is the original image and the second image is the created video with the problems I have.

I really need some help.

[image: This is the original Image]

[image: This is the created Video with the problems I have]

```
var outputSize = CGSize(width: 1920  , height: 1280)
var imagesPerSecond: TimeInterval = 0
var fps: Int32 = 0
var selectedPhotosArray = [UIImage]()
var imageArrayToVideoURL = NSURL()
var asset: AVAsset!
var imageCount = 1
```

My Code

```
func buildVideoFromImageArray() {

        for image in arrayOfImages {
            selectedPhotosArray.append(image)
        }


        imageArrayToVideoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory() + "/Documents/video1.MP4")
        removeFileAtURLIfExists(url: imageArrayToVideoURL)
        guard let videoWriter = try? AVAssetWriter(outputURL: imageArrayToVideoURL as URL, fileType: AVFileType.mp4) else {
            fatalError("AVAssetWriter error")
        }
        let outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecType.h264, AVVideoWidthKey : NSNumber(value: Float(outputSize.width)), AVVideoHeightKey : NSNumber(value: Float(outputSize.height))] as [String : Any]
        guard videoWriter.canApply(outputSettings: outputSettings, forMediaType: AVMediaType.video) else {
            fatalError("Negative : Can't applay the Output settings...")
        }
        let videoWriterInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaType.video, outputSettings: outputSettings)
        let sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String : NSNumber(value: kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB), kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: NSNumber(value: Float(outputSize.width)), kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: NSNumber(value: Float(outputSize.height))]
        let pixelBufferAdaptor = AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor(assetWriterInput: videoWriterInput, sourcePixelBufferAttributes: sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary)
        if videoWriter.canAdd(videoWriterInput) {
            videoWriter.add(videoWriterInput)
        }

        if videoWriter.startWriting() {
            let zeroTime = CMTimeMake(value: Int64(imagesPerSecond),timescale: self.fps)
            videoWriter.startSession(atSourceTime: zeroTime)

            assert(pixelBufferAdaptor.pixelBufferPool != nil)
            let media_queue = DispatchQueue(label: "mediaInputQueue")
            videoWriterInput.requestMediaDataWhenReady(on: media_queue, using: { () -> Void in
                //let fps: Int32 = 1
                let framePerSecond: Int64 = Int64(self.imagesPerSecond)
                let frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: Int64(self.imagesPerSecond), timescale: self.fps)
                var frameCount: Int64 = 0
                var appendSucceeded = true
                while (!self.selectedPhotosArray.isEmpty) {         // wird so lange ausgeführt, bis noch etwas im Array steht
                    if (videoWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData) {
                        let nextPhoto = self.selectedPhotosArray.remove(at: 0)  // foto wird aus dem selectedPhotosArray gelöscht

                        let lastFrameTime = CMTimeMake(value: frameCount * framePerSecond, timescale: self.fps)
                        let presentationTime = frameCount == 0 ? lastFrameTime : CMTimeAdd(lastFrameTime, frameDuration)
                        var pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer? = nil
                        let status: CVReturn = CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, pixelBufferAdaptor.pixelBufferPool!, &pixelBuffer)
                        if let pixelBuffer = pixelBuffer, status == 0 {
                            let managedPixelBuffer = pixelBuffer
                            CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(managedPixelBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: CVOptionFlags(0)))
                            let data = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(managedPixelBuffer)
                            let rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
                            let context = CGContext(data: data, width: Int(self.outputSize.width), height: Int(self.outputSize.height), bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(managedPixelBuffer), space: rgbColorSpace, bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue)
                            context!.clear(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CGFloat(self.outputSize.width), height: CGFloat(self.outputSize.height)))
                            let horizontalRatio = CGFloat(self.outputSize.width) / nextPhoto.size.width
                            let verticalRatio = CGFloat(self.outputSize.height) / nextPhoto.size.height
                            //let aspectRatio = max(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio) // ScaleAspectFill
                            let aspectRatio = min(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio) // ScaleAspectFit

                            let newSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: nextPhoto.size.width * aspectRatio, height: nextPhoto.size.height * aspectRatio)

                            let x = newSize.width < self.outputSize.width ? (self.outputSize.width - newSize.width) / 2 : 0
                            let y = newSize.height < self.outputSize.height ? (self.outputSize.height - newSize.height) / 2 : 0

                            context?.draw(nextPhoto.cgImage!, in: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height))
                            CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(managedPixelBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: CVOptionFlags(0)))
                            appendSucceeded = pixelBufferAdaptor.append(pixelBuffer, withPresentationTime: presentationTime)
                        } else {
                            print("Failed to allocate pixel buffer")
                            appendSucceeded = false
                        }
                    }
                    if !appendSucceeded {
                        break
                    }
                    frameCount += 1
                }
                videoWriterInput.markAsFinished()
                videoWriter.finishWriting { () -> Void in
                    print("-----video1 url = \(self.imageArrayToVideoURL)")

                    //self.asset = AVAsset(url: self.imageArrayToVideoURL as URL)
                    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                        PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: self.imageArrayToVideoURL as URL)
                    }) { saved, error in
                        if saved {
                            let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
                            fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]

                            let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .video, options: fetchOptions).firstObject
                            // fetchResult is your latest video PHAsset
                            // To fetch latest image  replace .video with .image
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        }

    }

    func removeFileAtURLIfExists(url: NSURL) {
        if let filePath = url.path {
            let fileManager = FileManager.default
            if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath) {
                do{
                    try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: filePath)
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print("Couldn't remove existing destination file: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
    }`
```

Comment: show your code.. we can't debug it from just output

Comment: Yes. I edited my post :)